# Save NSMutableArray to file with a TimeStamp?

Tags: objective-c, ios, timestamp, nsfilemanager

i am trying to **save a mutable array** into a file with the help of following code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *ArrayFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ex.dat"];

[Array writeToFile:ArrayFileName atomically:YES];
```

but i want to save the array with a **timestamp** so that i can retrieve it later accordingly. I am not sure how to create or **apply a timestamp to the array** and how to retrieve it. any help would be appreciated??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a `NSDictionary` with the `Array` and timestamp as members and @"array" and @"timestamp" as keys. Write the `NSDictionary` to the file similar to the way you have done it for `NSArray`.

Similarly, after retrieving the `NSDictionary` from the file, you can get the `NSArray` and timestamp

using

```
NSArray *array =  [dict valueForKey@"array"];
NSString *timestamp =  [dict valueForKey@"timestamp"];
```